Is there a phrase similiar to 'Insider Trading' that applies to the same/similar behaviour in the context of a Privately Owned company?
Insider Trading is defined as the the trading of a public company's stock or other securities (such as bonds or stock options) based on material, nonpublic information about the company.
Is there an equivalent term used to describe the same/similar behaviour in the context of a privately owned company? For Example, existing shareholder A sells their shares to another, pre-existing shareholder - shareholder B. Shareholder A has withheld relevant information from Shareholder B as part of the transaction - resulting in Shareholder B paying significantly more for the shares than they would have had Shareholder A not withheld this information (which was to the benefit of Shareholder A - and to the detriment of Shareholder B).

The same term is used for private companies. You can also use its synonym, Insider-dealing (see uk practical law)

The insider trading laws apply to private companies as well as to public companies, and to transactions with employees and employee stock plans as well as with third-party shareholders. (Lexology)

See also this post on LAW SE: Does "insider trading" apply to private companies?

I'm well impressed you found those links! Is corporate law your specialist subject?

@FumbleFingers No, I studied foreign languages. I just find my way around "words", even in less known fields. I am definitely not infallible, but the links I came across in my research for this particular matter seemed to unambiguously clarify the matter so...
